# Doorknob sticks if door closes hard

Tags: doors, doorknob

I'm having trouble with the doorknob on the door that goes from inside my house to the attached garage.  I installed a new doorknob (Kwikset brand, exterior) a while ago.  It works perfectly if the door is closed gently.  But, the door has self-closing hinges, and it tends to slam shut.  When it closes too hard, the doorknob sticks and is very hard to turn.  My wife and kids sometimes can't open it.  I was able to help a bit by adjusting the striker plate, but it's still an issue.  (I'm using the striker plate that came with the doorknob.)  What should I try next?

Removing the self-closing hinges isn't a good option.  I asked a local builder and learned that they're required by code.

Update:  I neglected to mention that the house came with some weather stripping all around this door frame.  It gets compressed between the door and the frame.  I tried to find the right balance in the striker plate position so that I don't have to slam the door to get it to stay closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the small half cylinder on the bolt is getting into the hole in the striker plate and jamming. This would mean that the striker plate is set too far out in the jamb.

It will be a pain to relocate the striker plate in a little, but you might have to do it. To test this, examine the movement of the small half cylinder as you close the door. You could use a felt marker to put a mark on the end of the half cylinder. The mark should stay visible as the bolt goes into the striker plate.

You could place a thin shim in the doorstop opposite the lock or two shims one above and one below and see if this stops the jamming when you close the door hard. If this stops the jamming you could just leave them in and use it that way

**EDIT**

If, due to the peculiarities of your door, you can't get the striker plate adjusted, you might consider going to a non-locking handle. The non-locking handles have a plastic bearing strip on the side of the bolt so that jamming would not be possible. You would then install a dead bolt lock requiring a key on the garage side.

One problem with the locking door handle on an exterior door is that it is easy to get locked out. After one or two episodes over 20 years we changed to a non-locking door handle and a deadbolt lock (which requires a key for locking) on both the front door and the door into the garage. Some neighbors have given us a key to their house and have had numerous lockouts (front door or rear French doors) in which they come to us for the key. Another neighbor also gave us a key for the same reason.

**EDIT**

Another possibility is to replace all or part of the weather stripping with some which is stiffer than the present one so that the door is stopped before it goes in far enough to allow the small bolt to enter the striker hole.

Comment: I'll try fiddling with the striker plate some more.  I don't want to move it too much, or else we'll have to slam the door to compress the weather stripping enough for it to latch closed.

Comment: What are your *observations* on the movement of the small half cylinder as you gently close the door? Then as you push on the door does the half cylinder move into the hole in the striker plate? This might not be the problem at all. It might be the main bolt is hanging up in the hole in the striker plate or on the striker plate. Is there clearance on the top and the bottom of the striker plate and the wood behind?

Comment: you could test by shimming the door to be a bit thicker by taping a few layers of card to the front edge. - if this helps the striker needs to be moved in.

Comment: @JimStewart I checked as you suggested.  When the doorknob gets stuck, the half cylinder does indeed move into the hole in the striker plate.  Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of room to adjust the plate.  It's already to the point where I sometimes have to press on the door a bit (compressing the weather stripping) to make it latch closed.  But if I press too hard (compressing the weather stripping more), it gets stuck.

Comment: What I would do then would be to insert a shim into the hole which the bolt goes into which would prevent the bolt from moving so far back (toward the doorstop) that the half cylinder goes past the edge of the striker plate and into the hole. Alternatively, you could affix a shim to the small tab in the striker plate (has a slot which looks like it's for prying out with a flat blade screwdriver) whose edge would prevent the half cylinder from going into the hole.  There must be a standard procedure for handling this.

Comment: I wonder if inserting a flat blade screwdriver in the slot in the tab and bending the tab out (into the hole) would keep the half cylinder from moving into the hole far enough to get jammed? Of course, bending this tab (or tang) in this way could make the situation worse!  Kwikset lock instructions state that bending this tang is for correcting minor door looseness. Instructions also say a keyed lock will **not** lock properly if the smaller bolt enters the strike hole.

Comment: @JimStewart I tried using a screwdriver to bend the tab in the striker plate as you suggested.  It worked like magic.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I thought it was possible, but a very long shot, that bending this tang would prevent the jamming. Sink me!

Comment: However, you still need to check that you can lock the door with the key from the garage side.